# Python Tornado BadYieldError for POST request with timeout

Tags: python, tornado, yield

I'm trying to write a post request for a Python Tornado server that sleeps for a second before sending a response back to a client. The server must handle many of these post requests per minute. The following code doesn't work because of `BadYieldError: yielded unknown object <generator object get at 0x10d0b8870>`

```
@asynchronous
def post(self):
    response = yield IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(time.time() + 1, self._process)
    self.write(response)
    self.finish()

@gen.coroutine
def _process(self, callback=None):
    callback("{}")
```

The server is to receive a post request, wait a second, and then return the result without blocking other requests. This is Python 2.7. How to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use callbacks or "yield", not both. So you could do:

```
@asynchronous
def post(self):
    IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(time.time() + 1, self._process)

def _process(self):
    self.write("{}")
    self.finish()
```

Or, better:

```
@gen.coroutine
def post(self):
    yield gen.sleep(1)
    self.write("{}")
    # Tornado calls self.finish when coroutine exits.
```

Comment: Both of these are blocking. :( Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Do you know a way to accomplish this without blocking?

Comment: Let me reiterate that... Do you have any idea why this code would act as blocking?

Comment: Why do you think it's blocking? You may be hitting a "browser with two tabs" gotcha: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/faq.html#my-code-is-asynchronous-but-it-s-not-running-in-parallel-in-two-browser-tabs

Comment: I'm observing logging as I exercise it using ab and wrk.

Comment: That's not enough info for me to help diagnose your issue. *What* logging are you observing, and what workload are you applying?